# How to make user logout upon token expiration in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

This is the token manager. All the necessary imports have been made. The token is stored in the async storage. I need to make user logout upon token expiration since the app is returning undefined whenever token expires in a day or two. And it's generating problem since upon expiration, the app only shows the loader screen and the user couldn't logout themselves.

```
const TokenManager = {
  restoreNewToken: async () => {
    const modelData = {
      client_id: TokenConfig.client_id,
      client_secret: TokenConfig.client_secret,
      grant_type: TokenConfig.grant_type,
    };
    const token = await DeviceStorage.getKey('token');
    const login_flag = await DeviceStorage.getKey('isloggedIn');
    const current_time = new Date().getTime() / 1000;

    if (login_flag === 'true') {
      //USER IS LOGIN
      const jwt = jwt_decode(token);

      if (current_time > jwt.exp) {
        try {
          //IF LOGIN ACCESS TOKEN IS EXPIRED
          const refresh_token = await DeviceStorage.getKey('refresh_token');

          var res = await axios.post(
            AppUrl.RefreshToken,
            qs.stringify({RefreshToken: refresh_token}),
            {
              headers: {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            },
          );
          let data = await res.data;
          if (data.error === 'invalid refresh token') {
            //IF INVALID REFRESH TOKEN: CLEAR ALL SAVED DATA AND GENERATE NEW ACCESS TOKEN
            await DeviceStorage.clearToken();
            const newToken = await DeviceStorage.getKey('refresh_token');
            var res = await axios.post(
              AppUrl.RefreshToken,
              qs.stringify(newToken),
            );
            let refresh_token_data = await res.data;
            await DeviceStorage.saveKey(
              'token',
              refresh_token_data.access_token,
            );

            return true;
          } else {
            //ELSE GENERATE NEW ACCESS TOKEN FOR LOGIN USER: IF REFRESH TOKEN IS EXPIRED
            var res = await axios.post(
              AppUrl.GetTemporaryToken,
              qs.stringify(modelData),
            );
            let temp_token = await res.data;
            await DeviceStorage.saveKey('token', data.access_token);
            return true;
          }
        } catch (error) {
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        //IF LOGIN TOKEN NOT EXPIRED: DO NOTHING
        return true;
      }
    } else {
      /**
       * if user is not login
       */
      if (token === null) {
        var res = await axios.post(
          AppUrl.GetTemporaryToken,
          qs.stringify(modelData),
          {
            headers: {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
          },
        );
        let data = await res.data;
        await DeviceStorage.saveKey('token', data.access_token);
        return true;
      } else {
        try {
          const jwt = jwt_decode(token);
          if (current_time > jwt.exp) {
            //GENERATE NEW TEMPORARY TOKEN IF EXPIRED
            var res = await axios.post(
              AppUrl.GetTemporaryToken,
              qs.stringify(modelData),
            );
            let data = await res.data;
            await DeviceStorage.saveKey('token', data.access_token);
            return true;
          } else {
            //IF TEMPORARY TOKEN IS NOT EXPIRED.
            return true;
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('error else', error);
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  },

  clearAndRestoreNewToken: async () => {
    try {
      await DeviceStorage.clearToken();
      const modelData = {
        client_id: TokenConfig.client_id,
        client_secret: TokenConfig.client_secret,
        grant_type: TokenConfig.grant_type,
      };
      var res = await axios.post(
        AppUrl.GetTemporaryToken,
        qs.stringify(modelData),
      );
      let data = await res.data;
      await DeviceStorage.saveKey('token', data.access_token);

      if (data) {
        await DeviceStorage.saveKey('token', data.access_token);
        return true;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error message', error)
      return false;
    }
  },
};

export default TokenManager;
```